# Can I offer one product at a different retail price depending on store view?

Tags: magento2, price, scope

I'm a relative newcomer.

I'm launching multiple stores under a single website, and was planning to rely on a particular functionality I saw in the official Price Scope documentation:

> "If the price configuration is set to the website level, the same product can be available at different prices in different stores."

*source: https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/catalog/catalog-price-scope.html*

But even with my price scope configuration set to "website", the above quote doesn't seem to be true. Can someone tell me if this is user error or if the documentation is just misleading/wrong?

To help illustrate, I want:

Store 1 : ProductA : $10

Store 2 : ProductA : $20

Store 3 : ProductA : $15

All stores are under the same website. Catalog price scope is set to "website" as recommended. But when I edit the price for "ProductA" in Store 1, it updates the price in Stores 2 & 3, as well. It seems impossible to customize product price by store, which I believe contradicts the quoted documentation?

I've come across a paid 'BSS Commerce' extension that allow you to set price scope to "Store View", but why is an extension necessary when Magento's own documentation purports to offer this functionality? Is the documentation wrong?

Comment: if you want the diffrent pricing for diffrent stores then you have to create the new website for each stores. Though there are extension available which supports this functionality.

As in documnets it self mention its either gobal or website, means price remains same for one website.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure **Scope** of price. To do this go to configurations

- On the Admin menu, click Stores. After that under Settings, select Configuration
- In the panel on the left under Catalog, select Catalog.
- Move down to the Price option. After that, change the Catalog Price Scope to one of following option:

  - Global
  - Website

[image]

If you change scope of price to Website then it will change in website level.
[image]

Reference: http://magestandard.com/configure-price-scope-magento-2/